# Display html formatting on liferay

Tags: html, liferay

I know it's a simple question, but I've got stuck here. How to display html formatting on liferay? I have tried to use outputText or outputLabel, but on the page view, it still display as is. For example (supposed backing.val value is `output <b>text</b>`):

```
<h:outputText value="#{backing.val}" />
  --> output <b>text</b>

<p:outputLabel value="#{backing.val}" />
  --> output <b>text</b>
```

I want the `text` is bold. How to do that? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `escape="false"` is vulnerable for [Cross Site Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Why don't you use `style` or `styleClass` instead?

In this case, your output from the bean should be just `text` and not `<b>text</b>`

```
<h:outputText value="#{backing.val}" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
```

OR

```
<h:outputText value="#{backing.val}" styleClass="boldTextClass"/>

.boldTextClass
{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `escape="false"` attribute:

```
<h:outputText value="#{backing.val}" escape="false"/>
```

More information can be found here:
http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_outputText.html